# Nullable operators problems in classes containing nullable objects of classes with enum fields

Tags: c#, nullable

I've a problem with using ??= operator for setting a value of enum field in class that is a nullable field of other class. Simplified example below:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var en = En.val2;
        var b = new B(new A());
        b.a?.en ??= en;
    }
}

public class A {
    public En en;
    
    public A() {
        en = En.val1;
    }
}

public class B {
    public A? a;
    
    public B(A a = null) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public enum En {
    val1,
    val2
}
```

The above gives an error: "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer".

I can still do it with simply checking if b.a is null, like this:

```
if(b.a != null){
    b.a.en = en;
}
```

Is there anyway to do what I want using nullable operators?

Comment: Presumably no. The left side must be something you can attach a value to. And here it could resolve to null and you can't change null.

Comment: No, there is no way, because if `b.a` is null, what will you assign to it? You only specify what you assign to `en`, which is not sufficient information for the operation you want to do

Comment: In short, you can only read from property if you are using Null-conditional operator `.?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way, because if `b.a` is null, what will you assign to it? You only specify what you assign to `en`, which is not sufficient information for the operation you want to do.

Anyways, the `b.a?.en ??= en;` operation and the piece of code below do NOT have the same meaning:

```cs
if (b.a != null) {
    b.a.en = en;
}
```

The null coalescing assignment translates to this:

```
if (b.a?.en == null) {
   b.a.en = en;
}
```

Which is clearly different. So I don't understand what you mean and what your code should do? So the correct answer depends on what you mean.

If you want to assign a value only if `b.a` is null (assign a default value), the solution would be:

```cs
if (b.a is null) {
   b.a = new A();
   b.a.en = en;
}
```

Or

```cs
b.a = b.a ?? new A();
b.a.en = en;
```

If you want to assign a value only if `b.a` is not null, then you should go with the `if` solution that you provided yourself.

Comment: It's simplified example (probably oversimplified) I have a class that stores parameters for some kind of operations. Each of this operations need parameters from one or two of this objects.  Assume I've operations: op1, op2, op3 and a class with objects of classes representing parameters for each operation (p1, p2, p3) and also different shared parameters (including bool b). Now I've op1, that needs only p1, so I fill p1, p2 and p3 are null. I've p2, which always needs p1 and p2 if b is true. Op3 only takes p3 params. I check if settings are correct in methods implementing each operation.

Answer (score 1):

Before you try to access `en` in `b.a`, You can use `??` operator to set the default value to `b.a`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var en = En.val2;
  var b = new B(new A());

  b.a = b.a ?? new A();
  b.a.en = en;
}
```

Comment: this will give `NullReferenceException` if `b.a` is null

Comment: @theemee and now?

Comment: and now it won't

Comment: I don't think you need to initialize A 'b.a = b.a ?? new A();' just add an 'if' to check its its not null and set the value ' b.a.en = en;' because as in question he wanted to set the value only if the a is not null

Answer (score 1):

In C#, when using `?` operator means check this value, if this value is not `null`, it gets the value of this value's property, otherwise gets the `default` value of value's property default. `??` operator means that if value is `null`, assign the value of member at the right side of `??` operator.

But at the left side of equality, if value is `null`, you can't assign a value for the property before create a new instance. That's why, you should check this condition using `if` keyword before assignment.

For your example:

```
if(b.a != null){
    b.a.en = en;
}
```

is valid one.

`b.a?.en ??= en;` this is incorrect syntax. as i can see, you especially want to use `a` property as nullable. Imo, In this situation, the best way is control `a` property with if before assignment operation of `en` property.

Comment: Thank's for clarification.